# Determine if a video is restricted to Premium Music members via the api

Tags: youtube-data-api

I host a wiki with many YouTube links and have a script that checks them all regularly to make sure they still exist and are not blocked (by region). I'd like to also check for videos that are inaccessible due to requiring Premium Music membership, but I cannot find that data point in the API documentation.

Example of a restricted Premium Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCRnj62bFOY

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: As far as I know, the info you're looking for is not available by means of YouTube Data API. But you may well issue a feature request to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As said [@stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) it doesn't seem that any YouTube Data API v3 endpoint meets your needs. However you can bypass the need of the YouTube Data API by downloading the webpage `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCRnj62bFOY` and checking whether or not this one contains "Music Premium". If so it is a Music Premium limited video.